# null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.noteArray') - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Why im receiving this error, but I already add the Constructor at my class.
the error just appear when I execute the android-run start and im getting this error.

> null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.noteArray')

```
export default class testPoject extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {noteArray: []}
}

render() {

    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
        return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} deleteMethod={ () => this.deleteNote(key)} />
    });

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>TODO LIST  </Text>
            </View>

            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollConainer}>

            </ScrollView>

            <View style={styles.footer}>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>
                        +
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TextInput style={styles.noteInputText}
                    placeholder="> Note"
                    placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    numberOfLines = {3}
                />

            </View>

    </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Well, 
Do one thing and it will work. Add a constructor and in that constructor declare the state.

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  noteArray:[{ 'note': 'Bingo'}],
  noteText:'',
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing a val and key to your map function?  noteArray is an array, not an object with key, value pairs.  Ether write noteArray as noteArray: {} or change your map function to work with a single element.